# ASP.NET: Nested master pages - how to pass content up multiple levels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know how to pass `Content/ContentPlaceholder` information from a page, up through it's master page, to the parent master page?

Like [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx), but with content defined in ChildFile (the page), being output in ParentMaster (q matster page one level higher in the nesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible. I haven't found a perfect solution to this myself, but usually what works well for a little amount of possibilities (such as a 3-choice navigation bar) is a deriving secondary master pages from the master page and using those in your views. Another solution one is would be using javascript to manipulate the master page's content. A third one would be to isolate the content you want to change from the client page into a separate contentplaceholder and specify that on the client page.

**Edit:** With the arrival of Razor, this problem is now perfectly solved: Simply put your variables in the ViewBag in the child view and read it in the layout.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: There's a better solution now... see my edit :-)

Comment: Ah, nice to know :) I'm stuck with WebForms view engine for know, but hopefully will be able to change soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use properties, pass them through and let the main master page decide what to do upon rendering

Comment: I should have added, that I'm using MVC, so aren't using code behind and such.